# Finding a molecular dynamics visualization library for C

Tags: simulation, visualization, molecular-dynamics, c

I asked this question over at stackoverflow, and got blasted for it.  I am currently working with legacy MD code written in C that my university uses, and haven't moved to a more modern library like OpenMM or mdcore (even though I fully want to).  Right now, our visualization routines are horribly out of date, and I am beginning to require something more advanced to make movies of my simulations.

The current visualization 'library' we use is a combination of OpenGL primitives via 'glew,' and it's X extension.  The researcher I work with a lot is in charge of the visualization routines, but here is my question:

Is there a newer, 'easy to use,' visualization library that I can link to that people could recommend?  I really need it for showing 3D simulation movies, and being able to do change perspectives, show multiple perspectives, etc, would be **awesome**.  Post processing would also be nice, since I write out binary files containing position information for all the objects in my simulation.  What do other people use for molecular dynamics simulations, where you have more than just spheres?  I have spheres, cylinders, squiggly lines, etc in the current incarnation.

Answer (score 7):

Have you had a look at [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/)?

I used it ages ago to produce movies from simulation snapshots. Way back then, it could read a sequence of PDB files, render them (or generate [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) scripts to raytrace them), and store them as individual images. I then used [`mencoder`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-images.html) to generate MPEG-4 files out of the stills. Those were the days.

I haven't used VMD since, but I can only imagine that it has gotten much, much better. Although it is intimately related to [NAMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/), if your own simulation can produce PDB files, there should be nothing stopping you from using it.

Comment: I will take a look at VMD, but our code doesn't write .pdb files by default.  Maybe I could come up with a way to convert the binary files to the text format in .pdb space, but since we are simulating abstract objects, it really doesn't look like it's quite what I am looking for.

Also, I had emailed you about mdcore more recently, and hadn't heard back on some functionality.  Just wondering if you were still around.

Comment: VMD can import a large number of input formats, for instance the CHARMM coordinate format and I believe it does XYZs (i.e., an XYZ trajectory) as well but you'd lose your topology information.

Answer (score 3):

Pedro's answer would have been mine. If you want to manage balls and sticks on your own, though, [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) is a modern library for such things.

Comment: I will check this out, as I think that VMD seems to mostly want to simulate the atoms and chains, but I simulate abstract objects instead of individual polymers/atoms.  So managing the spheres and sticks on my own is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

See also [QuteMol](http://qutemol.sourceforge.net) and 
[Free Molecular Visualization Software](http://www.umass.edu/microbio/rasmol/othersof.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) and [VESTA](http://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/). But you also have softwares like [Avogadro](http://avogadro.openmolecules.net/wiki/Main_Page) or [Molden](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/). Since I using VASP to simulate solids, I preferring VMD to visualize "molecular dynamics movies".

A very simple format for these movies is the XDATCAR, a example could be find [here](https://bitbucket.org/jkitchin/jasp/src/5a235ee2e6af/tests/ref/neb/02/XDATCAR). The last 3 blocks (of 13 lines) means 3 frames in your movie, before these blocks you can find the *lattice constant*, *3 components of the 3 Bravais lattice vectors* (3x3 matrix), *atomic species* and *number of atoms* for each species.